# Comment link not formatted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, hyperlinks

I left a link as a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353975/pointer-error-using-arrays-function-parameter#comment81660722_47353975). It did not show up as a proper link. Perhaps because the title has has parens, square brackets, and a forward slash.

Note: it does not show it, but I entered `https://` in the link.

It would be nice if (in comments) we could just enter the URL and have SO auto-magically display the page title. At least for links to other SO pages.

[image]

Comment: There is a `[0]` section in the brackets, which causes the markdown parser to be confused what is a link and what is not.

Comment: This is not something that can be fixed. Is `[How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]` the link text, or is `[How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) work?]`? We humans know it is the latter, but it is **damn hard to make the computer decide this**.

Comment: I fixed the link for you by escaping the `[` and `]` characters in the array subscription, by placing a backslash in front of both.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought that might be the case, but saw no mention of it in the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: the editing help is concise and focuses on the usual cases. The help page also points to the full Markdown spec for details,
 which has a section on [escaping with backslashes](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash).

Comment: This didn't need deleting, did it? I had an answer ready and everything, which should be helpful to both you and future visitors.

Comment: As long as my answer is at 0, you can still re-delete if you so desire.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I deleted because of the DVs and the fact the answer was in the docs. But I can leave open. I appreciate the time you took to answer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: voting on Meta indicates how many people agree that a bug should be fixed (or *is* a bug), not necessarily that the question is bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comment doesn't follow the permitted inline link format, because you have *more square brackets* inside your link text:

```
[How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33523585)
^                               ^ ^       ^
```

The parser sees `[How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]`, which is not followed by `(...)`, so there is no link there.

You can escape markdown characters [by using backslashes](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash):

```
[How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr\[0\]) work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33523585)
```

at which point the link works as expected:

> [How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33523585)

I fixed your comment.

You might be interested in the [*SE Comment Link Helper* user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper), which replaces Stack Exchange links with correctly formatted (escaped where needed) comment links. All you have to do is use a valid SE link in a comment and the helper will fetch the title, escape it, and wrap it in a Markdown link for you. That'll let you avoid having to manually escape special characters in titles.

Comment: The script looks like just what I want. Testing: [How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr\[0\]) work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33523585)